# How to rearrange items in FMDB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using FMDB in my project now

I can insert and delete my database , but how t o rearrange the items in FMDB ???

Now I turn the sqlite into a array with dictionaries .

And load the array to table view , than what should I do after I rearrange the tableview ???

Thanks for any reply or answer : )

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do...

Comment: sorry , I mean to rearrange the item's order in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a way to remember the order of items in your database. If that's the case, you'll have to add an extra column (called something like "item_order") and use the table view methods for moving cells to update the database.

Use the "item_order" to do the initial ordering when you first get the data to display.

Comment: Thanks ,sir , you right , I need to add a new column to record the items order , than I use table view index of row to update the DB.